# Как сделать переменную общей (любой язык)

Tags: переменные, delphi, php, java, ассемблер

Всем привет

Назрел такой вот вопрос, долго обдумывал, вроде сформулировалось. Как на каком-нибудь языке выдать переменную любому другому языку, т.е. чтобы любое другое приложение могло ее обработать?

Примерно реализацию представляю такой:

1. Берем адрес переменной
2. Берем длину в байтах
3. Передаем их процессу
4. Ждем изменений
5. Продолжаем работу

В метках указаны языки, которые я в ближайшее время сам смогу проверить, а так - любой. Ось - винда (если интересно про линь, создайте плз отдельную тему, т.к. я проверить не смогу)

Условие - не пользоваться пайпами, сокетами и прочее (разве что для передачи адреса и длины). Почему - ну, например, потому что передача по локальному сокету 200-метрового массива может занять больше времени, чем его обработка на ассемблере. Тут скорее всего адекватом будет запись в файл двух long int, т.к. это наиболее просто и стабильно для любого языка - записать и получить из файла. Соответственно, учесть, что приложение может не иметь доступа к этому участку памяти и обеспечить его.

Заготовка для дельфей(не в курсе, будет ли переменная доступна):

```
var myVar: String;
    varLink: Cardinal;
    varLength: Cardinal;
...
myVar := '0lol';
// myVar[1] - статус
varLink := Cardinal(Addr(myVar));
varLength := Cardinal(Length(myVar));
makeCommonVar(varLink, varLength); // собственно, оно
while myVar[1] = '0' do // пока в статусе ноль, отдыхаем
  begin
  Sleep(50);
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
ShowMessage(myVar); // показываем переменную
```

Возможно, сумбурно... Что-то типа "давайте напишем мостики между всеми языками". Можно вспомнить известный большинству ArtMoney - принцип работы где-то рядом.

Да, php там в метках особняком - я даже не в курсе, можно ли (и как) получить адрес(int) переменной.

Если код не грозится быть огромным - примеры приветствуются. Зачем это все? Ну, например, у разных языков разные задачи и где-то обработка переменной может быть быстрее/удобнее/проще, в конце концов.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Есть же куча вариантов, зачем изобретать велосипед ?

1. отображение файлов в память (mappedFiles)
2. dll
3. WM_DATA (вроде так сообщение называется)
4. Data Base ! ( :) )
5. memcache(d)

И самое главное, ДЛЯ ЧЕГО ЭТО может понадобится ?

Comment: Вот где-то из этой степи я что-то и ищу) Нужны, в идеале, куски кода для нескольких языков, чтобы их можно было скооперировать. Для чего - ну ближайшая практическая ценность - это нечто высоконагруженное в вебе. Пример банален - обработка 15-метровой выборки из БД на php, каждый раз для каждого запроса разное. Можно извращаться с кэшем, оптимизировать и т.п, но php это все равно убьет) А можно подключить что-то ассемблерное. Именно для php - это самый прозрачный пример как для самого тормозного языка, но и просто перекладывание задач с одного языка на другой пригодится.

Comment: вот на [дельфи][1]


  [1]: http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/delphi_windows_API/f348.shtml

Answer (score 3):

Короче, из всего этого потока сознания я понял, что Вам нужно придумать, как передать данные из одного процесса в другой. Причем в обоих процессах выполняются программы, написанные на разных языках. Напомню, что каждый процесс выполняется в своем виртуальном адресном пространстве памяти, и получить доступ в пространство другого процесса просто так не может. Для обмена данными придумано несколько решений. Все они давно известны и реализованы на большинстве современных ОС. Пайпы, сокеты, сигналы, очереди сообщений. Для Ваших целей, мне каж, подойдет разделенная память. Это когда некая области памяти становится доступной обоим процессам.  И не важно, на каком языке написаны программы, поскольку все эти IPC реализованы на уровне ядра ОС. Главное, чтобы этот язык поддерживал данный тип IPC или хотя бы давал возможность вызывать API-функции системы. И еще: данные передаются не от языка к языку, от программы к программе.

Comment: > любому другому языку, т.е. чтобы любое другое приложение могло ее обработать

Можеть быть, сумбурно написано, но имелось в виду следующее: в приложении(языке, на которым оно написано) должны был способы (получить AND передать) эту переменную. Можете подсказать пример такой обертки для shared memory (dll, например), которую любой из хотя бы перечисленных языков мог использовать *как на отдачу, так и на прием*?

Comment: Если нужно что-то очень высокопроизводительное, пиши на С/С++. Ассемблер не трогай, если не мазохист. В указанных Вами языках я не очень большой спец, так что гугль + справочники.

Comment: Мне ближе дельфи с асм, ну и сам асм - что-то такое родное, из детства)) Ну понял примерно, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

я бы посоветовал порыть в сторону COM объектов, либо DLL

Comment: я бы даже предпочел COM объект. подойдет для любого языка поддерживающего ком

Answer (score 1):

Да похоже только DLL ну или писать переменную в файл, хотя это не кошерно.